# Is there a way to use strace to trace different parts of a command pipeline?

Tags: linux, strace, trace

I have a pipeline like this:

```
command1 | command2
```

Is there a way to trace both commands simultaneously?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a single trace with:

```
strace -f sh -c 'command1 | command2'
```

The "-f" will "follow" fork calls into the child processes (so you'll also get any sub-commands invoked by command1 or command2, which may or may not be what you want.)  Also, you'll get a trace of the `sh` process too.  If you want each processes output in a separate file, the "-ff" option will trace subprocesses and append the PID to the "-o" filename, as in:

```
strace -ff -o trace sh -c 'command1 | command2'
```

This should create separate `trace.<PID>` files for each forked child.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put `strace` before each command in the pipeline and redirect the stderr to a different file for convenient analysis:

```
strace -o trace1.out command1 | strace -o trace2.out command2
```